# Difference between $1$ and $\bar 1$ of Cayley table

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, notation

Why do we write $1$ as $\bar 1$  in a Cayley table, instead of usual $1$? What is the difference?

Comment: Because it's technically am equivalence class of numbers, not just a single number.